# Passport login failing using email instead of username

Tags: node.js, passport-local

I am using 'email' instead of 'username' for my passport local instance. Below is my login route. I also have included the part of my user model where I set username to be email. I am sending the exact same login data used to create the user.

**Login route**

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
   successRedirect: "/",
   failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res) {});
```

**Added to user model**

```
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField : 'email' });
```

Comment: And what strategy is there? The passport needs a strategy. [Github - passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)

Comment: @AMS it is using the default, notice the `local` in the OP

Comment: Yes I saw but passaport is a set of rules, what is the rule to validate this email? After validating the passport will do something, in your case you want to save the email in the right bank? And if the validation of the email fails, it refuses and does not record in the database, would it?

Answer (score 0):

if you using local strategy, you need to define passport strategy variables. see docs http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/

> add new config file for passport

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

User is the schema of your mongoose. And replace username with email.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might switch to that method but currently I have `UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField : 'email' });` set in my user model. That solved it

Comment: If I were to do it your way, say I want it put inside `middleware/passport` how can I do it so my routes stay in the same format, ie I can add prefixes in my app.js and I don't have to do weird stuff in my app.js

Comment: create a config file then declare new variable that require the config file